# Have JSF tag NOT render an HTML tag

Tags: html, jsf

I do the front end HTML for a JSF team. I often run into the JSF tags being used rendering HTML of their own. It's often a SPAN and isn't usually a problem, but once in a while we have this:

```
<table>
<h:panelGroup rendered="[jsf logic]">
    <tr><td>#{jsfVariable}</td></tr>
</h:panelGroup>
</table>
```

Which will render this:

```
<table>
<span>
    <tr><td>Hello World.</td></tr>
</span>
</table>
```

I've been reading through JSF tag documentation but can't find a specific mention of a way to tell the JSF tag to only render the child HTML, not the tag itself as an HTML element. Is there a JSF attribute to tell it "don't render a span"? Or is there a JSF tag that will not render as HTML, but still allow for use of JSF variables within?

Comment: I realize you're probably doing something more complex, but why not just use -> ...td><h:outputText rendered="[jsf logic]" /></td>... Alternatively you could write a custom component that had children but rendered nothing but that seems like a lot of work for something that might be an easy work around (composite components or simple redesign of the html)

Comment: Yes, that's the problem with simplifying the examples. ;) I agree, in this specific example, your solution would make perfect sense. But yea, in actual use, our code is usually much more complex.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The `<span>` is only generated if you give the `<h:panelGroup>` an attribute which **must** end up in HTML, such as `id`, `styleClass`, etc. In your given example, the `<h:panelGroup>` has only a `rendered` attribute, so nothing will be generated to the HTML.

So, to achieve your requirement, just remove all attributes other than `rendered` from the `<h:panelGroup>`, exactly as you did in your own question example.

Comment: Seems somewhat obvious in hindsight! I didn't ever see that mentioned in any of the docs I read, though. Thanks!

Comment: You're welcome. If you're using JSP's successor Facelets instead of JSP, then an alternative is `<ui:fragment>`. It has no HTML attributes, so you wouldn't be able to "accidently" specify any one.

Comment: This is only valid for static markup. What if I want to update the `<tr>` via ajax to update its render status? The only solution I find is updating whole table or all components in the cell of the row. Mojarra renders the `span` above the table resulting in wrong update. `<h:panelGroup id="pnl"><h:panelGroup rendered="#{value}"><tr>...</tr></h:panelGroup></h:panelGroup>` is not working.

Comment: @djmj: OmniFaces has an `Ajax#updateRow()` you may find helpful.

Comment: Looks good for repeating data with data binding. I conditionally want to render/update html rows with input components depending on other input data / selections. Primefaces `panelGrid` looks promising even if i prefer simple html if no design needed.